# P-norm and spectral radius inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Could someone help me with this proof? I have no idea how to begin.
$$\rho(M) \leq  \|M^k\|^{1/k}_p $$    with $M$ an $n\times n$ matrix, $k$ is a natural number. What can you say about $k \to \infty$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you define $\|M\|_p$?

Comment: It might help to review the definition of the spectral radius, and using that with the definition you have for $\|M\|_p$, sketch an approach to the desired proof.  Think especially about the relation of $\rho(M)$ and $\rho(M^k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working over $\mathbb{C}$ with the definition $$\rho(M) = \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|$$

We have $\rho(M) \le \|M\|$. Indeed, for $|\lambda| > \|M\|$, the matrix $M - \lambda I$ is invertible with the inverse $$(M - \lambda I)^{-1} = -\frac1\lambda\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{M^n}{\lambda^n}$$

Note that the series converges absolutely because of $\lambda > \|M\|$. Therefore $\lambda \notin \sigma(M)$.

Now the spectral mapping theorem implies $\sigma(M^k) = \sigma(M)^k$ so

$$\rho(M)^k = \rho(M^k) \le \|M^k\|$$

and hence $\rho(M) \le \|M^k\|^{1/k}$.

---

Prepare for some complex analysis.

Taking the infimum above over $k \in \mathbb{N}$ gives $$\rho(M) \le \inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \|M^k\|^{1/k} \le  \liminf_{k\to\infty} \|M^k\|^{1/k}$$

Consider the open ball $\Delta = B\left(0, \frac1{\rho(M)}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Let $\phi$ be an arbitrary (bounded) linear functional on the space of matrices. For $\lambda \in \Delta$ the matrix $I - \lambda M$ is invertible so define $f : \Delta \to \mathbb{C}$ as $f(\lambda) = \phi\left((I - \lambda M)^{-1}\right)$. We will show that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Delta$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda \to \lambda_0} \frac{f(\lambda) - f(\lambda_0)}{\lambda - \lambda_0} &= \phi\left(\lim_{\lambda \to \lambda_0} \frac{(I-\lambda M)^{-1} - (I - \lambda_0 M)^{-1}}{\lambda - \lambda_0}\right)\\
&= \varphi\left(\lim_{\lambda \to \lambda_0} \frac{[(I-\lambda M) - (I-\lambda_0 M)](I-\lambda M)^{-1}(I - \lambda_0 M)^{-1}}{\lambda - \lambda_0}\right)\\
&= -\varphi\left(\lim_{\lambda \to \lambda_0} (I-\lambda M)^{-1}(I - \lambda_0 M)^{-1}\right)\\
&= -\varphi\left( (I-\lambda_0 M)^{-2}\right) \in \mathbb{C}
\end{align}

Hence $f$ has a Taylor series on $\Delta$, meaning there exists a unique sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$f(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \lambda^n , \forall \lambda \in \Delta$$

If $|\lambda| < \frac1{\|M\|}$, then $\|\lambda M\| < 1$ so check that 
$$(I - \lambda M)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^nM^n$$

Acting on this with $\phi$ gives

$$f(\lambda) = \phi\left((I - \lambda M)^{-1}\right) = \phi\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^nM^n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi(M^n)\lambda^n$$

Since the Taylor series of $f$ is unique, we conclude $\alpha_n = \phi(M^n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Let $\lambda \in \Delta$. We in particular have $\phi(M^n)\lambda^n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ so $(\phi(M^n)\lambda^n )_{n=0}^\infty$ is bounded. Since $\phi$ was arbitrary, the Uniform Boundedness Principle implies that $(\lambda^n M^n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence of matrices. Hence $\exists C(\lambda) > 0$ such that $\|\lambda^n M^n\| \le C(\lambda), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Therefore $$\|M^n\|^{1/n}  \le \frac{C(\lambda)^{1/n}}{|\lambda|}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$ so $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|M^n\|^{1/n} \le \frac1{|\lambda|}$.

Since $\lambda$ was an arbitrary number such that $\rho(M) < \frac1{|\lambda|}$, we conclude that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|M^n\|^{1/n} \le \rho(M)$$

Finally we get

$$\rho(M) \le \inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \|M^k\|^{1/k} \le  \liminf_{k\to\infty} \|M^k\|^{1/k} \le \limsup_{k\to\infty} \|M^k\|^{1/k} \le \rho(M)$$

so $$\rho(M) = \inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\|M^k\|^{1/k} = \lim_{k\to\infty}\|M^k\|^{1/k} $$

Comment: Thank you, I did ask these question at StackExchange because my professor would not answer (possible question at an examination), yesterday he has made up his mind and he agrees with the above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $\| M \|_{p}=\displaystyle\max_{x\neq 0 }\frac{\|Mx\|_p}{\|x\|_p}$.

Let $M\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ and $v\in \Bbb C^n, v \neq 0$ be such that $Mv=\lambda v$ with $|\lambda|=\rho(M)$. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any norm on $\Bbb C^n$, then it holds
$$\rho(M)=|\lambda|\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\|}=\frac{\|Mv\|}{\|v\|}\leq \| M \|_{V\to V}:=\max_{x\neq 0 }\frac{\|Mx\|}{\|x\|}.$$
Now, since for every $k$ it holds $\rho(M^k)=\rho(M)^k$, we deduce that
$$\rho(M)^k=\rho(M^k)\leq \| M^k \|_{V\to V}$$
which implies the desired result for $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|_p$.

The case $k\to \infty$ is known as [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).

The main idea is the following: First, note that $\| M^{m+k}\|_{V\to V}\leq \| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}\| M^{k}\|_{V\to V}$ for all $k,m\geq 1$, then use [Fekete's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Properties) on $a_m=\ln(\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V})$ to show that
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}^{1/m}=\inf_{m\geq 1}\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}^{1/m}.$$
By the argument above, we have that 
$$\rho(M)\leq \lim_{m\to \infty}\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}^{1/m}$$
For the other direction, note that
$$\rho(M)=\lim_{m\to \infty}\|M^mv\|^{1/m}\leq \lim_{m\to \infty}\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}^{1/m}\|v\|^{1/m}= \lim_{m\to \infty}\| M^{m}\|_{V\to V}^{1/m}$$